# How to re-sum values during the second GROUP BY statement

Tags: sql, group-by

Here is the output I have: [image: Table]

As you can see on the right side, the values are obtained from sum() function from a previous group by, but I still have non-unique names in the table. How can I make it so that all names in table are unique and the values on the right are summed for non-unique members.

Here is my query in case it helps:

```
select alp_customer.first, alp_customer.last, alp_customer.email, sum(alp_orderline.order_price)
from alp_orderline
inner join alp_orders on alp_orderline.order_id = alp_orders.order_id
inner join alp_customer on alp_orders.cust_id = alp_customer.cust_id
group by alp_orderline.order_id
```

I hope I made my question clear enough, I am very new to SQL and wasnt able to find solution online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use  `alp_customer.first, alp_customer.last, alp_customer.email` these columns in group by

```
select alp_customer.first, alp_customer.last, alp_customer.email, sum(alp_orderline.order_price)
from alp_orderline
inner join alp_orders on alp_orderline.order_id = alp_orders.order_id
inner join alp_customer on alp_orders.cust_id = alp_customer.cust_id
group by alp_customer.first, alp_customer.last, alp_customer.email
```